# What would cause 3 bursts of FM radio interference every ~3.5 seconds

Tags: rfi, fm

I’m trying to locate the source of some interference on the FM band — it’s audible as 3 quick staccato bursts of brownish noise approximately every 3.5 seconds. It’s more pronounced at the low end of the commercial FM radio band.

Comment: Does it go away if you turn off your cellphone? (I'm starting with the easiest.) If not, try and unplug your TV, turn off your computer and other electronics.

Comment: Apologies for not having the right vocab/skillset for the community — from my approach it should be pretty clear I come from a software engineering background. Please feel free to edit for a better fit, or suggest a better forum for this type of question so I can put it where it belongs

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Please don't worry about having the right vocabulary or skillset; a great many of our users came here by the very same path that brought you, so you're in excellent company.  We're here to help you learn, and no experience is required.

Answer (score 3):

Solved! It was the wireless charging pad integrated into the top surface of the device, which thankfully they provided a means to disable.